# Unable get NuGet to work with the CurrentUser scope

Tags: powershell, nuget

I need to make requests behind socks 5 from the PS script. PS version requirement: <= 5.1. Also, it should work without admin rights. So I can't just upgrade PS or .NET to solve the issue. I want to use the HttpToSocks5Proxy package for that purpose but got trouble with installation.

I'm trying to install the HttpToSocks5Proxy package for the CurrentUser scope. I've installed NuGet with this command:

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force -Scope CurrentUser
```

But I still cannot install the package. I'm doing it with this command:

```
Install-Package -Force -Scope CurrentUser HttpToSocks5Proxy
```

and getting this:

```
*Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'HttpToSocks5Proxy'*
```

Interestingly, *Get-PackageSource* shows only PSGallery. I've tried to register NuGet with Register-PackageSource, but whenever I pass in `-Location` I get the next:

```
Register-PackageSource : MSG:SourceLocationNotValid
```

I don't understand how to install NuGet :( Thanks.

Comment: This question is an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  What are you trying to achieve, by "installing" a .NET library package in PowerShell?

Comment: I need to make requests behind socks 5 from the PS script. PS ver requirement: <= 5.2. Also, it should work without admin rights. So that I can't just upgrade PS or .NET to solve the issue. But this library can.

Comment: I can reproduce here with PS 5.1, although it works in PS 7. In my case it's *possibly* related to the package providers - if I try ```Get-PackageSource``` I see the "location" for nuget.org is ```https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json``` - PS 5.1 tries to probe by hitting the url ```https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json/FindPackagesById()?id='FoooBarr'``` which gives a HTTP 400 response. I don't know whether "correcting" this to use the V2 endpoint will work, or whether that will also break PS 7, but hopefully this gives you an line to investigate...

Comment: Can you also show the full command you're calling for ```Register-PackageSource```?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use v2 and v3 (with many variations) without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've built a command that solves the issue. I hope someone could save a few hours thanks to this solution :)

```bash
Find-PackageProvider -Force -Name NuGet | Install-PackageProvider -Force -Scope CurrentUser
Register-PackageSource -Name nuget.org -Location https://www.nuget.org/api/v2 -ProviderName NuGet
Install-Package -Force -Scope CurrentUser HttpToSocks5Proxy
```